# Writing memory for parameters in PyTorch `named_parameters`

Tags: python, pytorch, named-parameters

```
class MyAlgo(torch.optim.Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, params, model):

        self.model = model

    def step(self, closure = None):

        for name, param in self.model.named_parameters(): 
            param = "a Tensor in size of param"
```

In PyTorch, can the returned `param` from `model.named_parameters()`
method written as the approach above?
**An answer (updated):** one should use an in-place operation: param.copy_(torch.Tensor-like) to write into `param`.

Another question would be, is this the best approach to manipulate parameters? **Could [self.param_groups](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v1.2.0/_modules/pytorch_transformers/optimization.html)-based approach have any better efficiency benefits?**

Comment: The answer is yes. It is possible to get param like that.

Comment: @BIgG, your answer appears to be not what I have been looking for. I try to update the model parameters by the line `param = something`, but it turns out that no parameters are changing over several calls of `step()`.

Comment: To `write` into `param`, one should use an in-place operation: 
`for name, param in self.model.named_parameters(): param.copy_(torch.Tensor-kind)`.